Is it possible to transform a pointwise product into a convolution?
Let $A(k)$ and $B(k)$ be signals in the wavenumber domain. Is it possible to find a function $G(k)$ such that $G(k) \ast B(k) = A(k)B(k)$? Preferably a closed form solution.
I tried the following iterative method (we can demonstrate it using the convolution theorem), but it doesn't seem to work:
for $n$ in itermax:

$G_n(k) = F\left[{\frac{F^{-1}[A(k)B_n(k)]}{F^{-1}[B_n(k)]}}\right]$

Update $B_n(k)$ with some function that demands $G_n(k) \ast B_n(k) = A(k)B_n(k)$


I expected it would converge, so a correct approximation of the filter $G(k)$ and of the signal $B(k)$ would be computed, but it doesn't work. Any thoughts?
Edit:
Although it seems pointless, there is a specific equation (with which I'm working) that could be easily solved if this conversion were possible. On the other hand, it has no easy solution without it (or it would be too expensive).

Wouldn't it be rather pointless to convert a pointwise product (which requires $n$ multiplications and $n$ additions ($n-1$ additions for the anal-retentive) to compute) into a convolution which requires $n^2$ multiplications and additions to compute? The conversion_could_ be done, but why bother doing so?

@DilipSarwate Although it seems pointless, there is a specific equation (with which I'm working) that could be easily solved if this conversion were possible. On the other hand, it has no easy solution without it (or it would be too expensive). I will add this information to the post.

Is $A(k)B(k)$ an element-wise multiplication or an inner product? What are the dimensions of all the variables?

It is an element-wise multiplication. Their domain is the wavenumber domain, which means that it could be 1D (kx), 2D (kx,ky) or 3D (kx,ky,kz). @Baddioes

@LucasBitencourt You may want to take a look at the comments/answers in this post, although the application is a bit different than yours. And as Dilip mentioned, it seems a bit odd to convert an element wise multiplication to a convolution.

Is $n$ the timestamp, or is $k$. Is $A(k)$ supposed to be indexed by $n$ as well or no?

Here is a solution that doesn't require the vectors $A$ and $B$ have a certain structure, which ends up being the reverse of what you did:
$$G=\mathcal F^{-1}\left\{\frac{\mathcal F\{AB\}}{\mathcal F\{B\}}\right\}$$
Note that this solution is for a circular convolution. Here is Matlab code that demonstrates it in action:
A = rand(5,1);
B = rand(5,1);
G = ifft(fft(A.*B)./fft(B));
disp(conv(G,[B;B],'same') - A.*B);

An example of the output is below, which is effectively zero for all elements, as expected:
1.0e-15 *

 0.0416
      0
-0.0555
-0.0833
 0.1110

